# Cannot Convert Decimal To Int

Tags: c#, int, decimal

i have this error, and i want to fix it, it says cannot convert decimal to int, i dont know where to put (int) or (decimal).

The character moves 8pix/s and its stored in a decimal.

Heres the code

```
     int[,,] Map = new int[151, 151, 11];
     decimal GuyY = 1;
     decimal GuyX = 1; //Placeholder for other math

     if (Map[GuyX / 32, Math.Ceiling(GuyY / 32) - 1, 1] = 1)
     {
     }
```

Comment: but `guyX` and `guyY` are *not* initialized?

Comment: You should explain why you use decimals for this code

Comment: Use 32.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices [,] of an array have to be integers. Dividing a decimal `GuyX` by an integer `32` results in a `decimal` which is not valid as an index.

Also, you need to use `==` to evaluate a boolean expression.

Resulting code would be:

```
if (Map[(int)(GuyX / 32), (int)Math.Ceiling(GuyY / 32) - 1, 1] == 1)
{

}
```